# How to make one to many relationship that uses many diffrent models in Django?

Tags: django

I'm writing one of first Django apps and
I have recipe model like this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

and also many other models for steps in recipe:

```
class BaseStep(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('recipe.Recipe', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TextStep(BaseStep):
    text = models.CharField(max_lengh=4096)

class ListStep(BaseStep):
    list_elements = models.CharField(max_length=2048)

class TimerStep(BaseStep):
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

above models are simplified, what makes them pointless but I need them this way. I know that normally I would specify `ForeignKey` in `BaseStep` so that I have some reference, like this:

```
recipe = models.ForeignKey('recipe.Recipe', related_name='steps', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but this simply doesn't work, because it's inherited by child models, with is not OK because related_name needs to be unique. In the end I need to have field `steps` in `Recipe` that will return array or queryset of all the steps. I know that Proxy Models can do something like that but using it here is stupid. Now that I'm thinking, is making a `@property` function in Recipe, that will query all steps and return python array out of them class a good idea? I need to serialize it in the end, for rest endpoint.

Comment: Can you make `BaseStep` an abstract model? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Take a look at https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: As for the BaseStep it already is an abstract model.

Comment: django-polimorphic looks like solution for me! Great, but how do I flag that as an answer?

Comment: Now, you can ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable. This offers tools to easily work with model inheritage.